# Why Is Content Entered In Classic Editor Not Displaying on Page?

Tags: visual-editor, plugin-contact-form-7

I have a contact page on my website, where I've entered the shortcode for Contact Form 7 in the page editor:

[image]

But the contact form isn't displaying on the front-end:

[image]

Instead only the content from the `Home Page Template` is displaying along with the title of the page.

I'd rather not put the code for Contact Form 7 in the `Home Page Template` because that template is also being used for all of the other pages on the site.

Any idea as to why nothing from the page editor is showing up on the site?

My reading settings look like this:

[image]

And I have the WordPress loop in my `index.php` file:

```
<?php

get_header();

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <article class="post">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title()?></a></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </article>

    <?php endwhile;

else:
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

endif;

get_footer();

?>
```

Is this problem somehow related to the new WordPress release? I'm having this issue with all of the other pages on the site as well.

Site is live here: https://refresh.drawyourpets.com/

Your guidance is appreciated!

Comment: what version of WP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Shortcodes with hyphens can cause [problems](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Hyphens) and in WP 5, Gutenberg will not accept them, so it is possible this is the issue you are facing. To see if this is the problem, I suggest you install the [CF7 Smart-grid extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) which replaces the cf7 shortcode with cf7Form, thus removing the hyphens.  This will at least strike out this possibility.